# I want to calculate the probability of a special situation in match-three-tiles games

Tags: probability

I am new here and it is my first time asking a question.

I'm making a match-three game, like Candy Crush or Bejewed.

For people who do not know, basically there will be a game board, the size may vary, and within the grid there will be different types of tiles. You want to match three same tiles in a straight line to cancel them and score.

And now I want to figure out how large my grid should be, as it will majorly be played on mobile devices, it is impossible to have a very large grid, or it will be hard for players to choose tiles.

However, as the tiles are randomly generated, there will be a chance where in the board, there is no move to make any match. So I cannot make the grid very small either.

So I want someone to help me make a formula that given the grid size x*y, and z types of tiles, what is the probability that there will be no possible move on the board?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are cancellations just based on horizontal and vertical matches?  Or also on diagonal matches?  (2) If more than three in a row, do all get cancelled?  Or only three at a time?

Comment: Another question: how do you define "move"?  Will this be more in the style of qbeez where you simply point out where is a match and that is your move?  Or is a move more in line with something like bejeweled where a "move" corresponds to rearranging pieces in such a way as to create a match, and any matches that naturally occur are immediately scored whether the immediate result of switching tiles or not?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! First, yes, just horizontal and vertical. Second, more than three also count. But I guess if you cannot find any three, you cannot find more than that either. Actually, let me be more specific. The situation I am saying is that, there is no two same tiles that are already next to each other, nor two same tiles with a different one in between them. That's is the only thing I need. In other word, no a-a or a-b-a(also included vertical) patterns in the entire grid. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume three-in-a-row diagonally won't count as a cancel; just horizontally and vertically. I will also assume that by "possible move" you mean swap the position of two horizontally or vertically adjacent tiles. I will set minimum rows, columns, and number of colors to 3.

I know this isn't very elegant, but I built a Monte Carlo Simulation. I get this as a practical result:

Probability = $ \frac{1}{1+10^{-\alpha}}$ where $ \alpha $ is given by: 
$$ 0.24 * \frac{Rows*Columns - |Rows-Columns|}{Colors - \sqrt{Colors}} -0.578 $$

It should hold true enough for most Color/Row/Column combinations you might expect to use in your game. (fails for many colors and few rows/columns or for too many rows or columns)

Comment: Hello! Will this work to an 8x8 grid with 6 type of tiles? Thank you! You are very kind :)

Comment: The calculate the probability of a legal move possible with a randomly assorted 8x8 grid with 6 types of tiles we have $$\alpha = 0.24*\frac{64}{6-\sqrt{6}} - 0.578 = 3.75$$ $$P = \frac{1}{1+10^{-\alpha}} = \frac{1}{1+10^{-3.75}} = 0.9998$$ So this combination will virtually always have at least one legal move.

Comment: Thanks man! I will look more into the Monte Carlo Simulation myself.